# binding a winforms control's property to multiple object properties

Tags: c#, data-binding

I am looking for a solution to bind a property of a windows forms control (Text of a button or a label) to multiple properties of one (or more) objects via a formatting string. Basically, the displayed text on a button should look like "static text $1 more static text $2" where $1 is bound to the to the property of an object and $2 is bound to a different property of the same or a different object. Is there an easy way to accomplish that?

Answer (score 1):

You could encapsulate Property1 and Property2 in a third property that takes and returns the formatted string.

```
public string EncapsulatingProperty
{
    get { return "static text" + property1 + "more" + property2; }
    set { /* Parse the static text into the two variables */ }
}
```

Comment: you'd better use string.Format

Comment: Unfortunately, the "static text" is not known to the object. I want to be able to define it at the time I establish the binding. I could, of course, implement a property or method that allows me to pass the static text to the object, but that wouldn't work if $1 is bound to the property of a different object than the one $2 is bound to.
I thought of writing a "Combiner"-class which is bound to the properties of the (two) objects and has a property that returns the formated string, but I was hoping that there may be an existing solution for something like that.

Comment: I don't think the kind of thing you're hoping for exists in the framework.

Answer (score 0):

To add on Eric's response, [Understanding Simple Data Binding](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/simpledatabinding.aspx) can provide a good read on the subject.

Answer (score 0):

IF you are dealing with WPF/Silverlight for the UX, I believe you can write a ValueConverter to handle the proper displaying of the data... and in some instances, convert the values back.

Comment: He's doing WinForms (according to the question title).

Comment: Yea... a year later, I realize I read the question wrong. Apologies Eric J.